# Improve Regex to get 6 digit Date (MMDDYY)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm currently using:

```
[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}
```

to match a 6 digit date.  Is there a way to make this more restrictive, my issue is that I have other 6-8 digits digits contained in the text and I am getting the occasional false positive in the non-date sequence.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks !

p.s Should Say that the year will always be above 2000 and less then Current Date, hence the restriction on the year.

Comment: Do you really *have* to use a regular expression here? Can you not just attempt to parse it?

Comment: @JonSkeet wouldn't the false positive still parse ?  I suppose I will have the problem either way tho

Comment: You can use DateTime.TryParse along with a date comparison. It's really simple and easier to maintain then a regex. Except onlye if you MUST run it at client side, though

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna: No, they wouldn't. That's the point - by using something which actually parses the value as a date rather than just treating it as a sequence of characters, you can get semantic validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an actual date parser for this, not only to make it simpler to parse actual possible values (i.e. month 13 is not valid) but also to be prepared for leap years etc.

Usually the date parser in your favorite language should be able to parse a string in the MMDDYY format and give some kind of feedback if it fails.

Comment: A date parser doesn't do you any good for finding the 6 digit date code in a bunch of text. It's only useful once you actually have it extracted and isolated.

Comment: @RhodesianHunter There's no point in making the extraction more complex. Just extract all date-like numbers using a simple and fast expression and then attempt to parse them properly.

Comment: everyone's use case is different. 

In my case parsing every 6 digit number into a LocalDate object and catching exceptions for the bad ones would be far more complex (and far less performant) than narrowing down to the most likely candidates up front with a good regex.

I only comment because your answer does not answer the OP's question, which was how to improve their regex.

"Improve Regex to get 6 digit Date (MMDDYY)"

Answer (score 2):

One improvement, for only 12 months, 31 days, and 2000 to 2012.

```
(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(?:200[0-9]|201[1-2])
```

*I'm aware that some of those dashes aren't necessary; added them for readability.*

Then you can go further, for 28, 30, or 31 days depending on the month.

```
(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])31|(?:0[13-9]|1[0-2])(?:29|30)|(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))(?:200[0-9]|201[1-2])
```

There is technically a way to figure out leap years but that's going a little overboard.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html
BTW: You won't be able to handle leap years with just a regex (Although theorically possible it's impractical). You should use a proper date parser.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `[0-1]\d[0-3]\d[2-9]\d{3}`
but imposible interact with current date